# Coded UI - Keyboard.sendkeys - Sending path of a file containing special characters

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, coded-ui-tests, qtp

I'm trying to send the path of a file (dynamically) containing special characters in it using keyboard.sendkeys in codedui:

```
string filepath="I:\^abc\abc\filename.csv";
Keyboard.SendKeys(filepath);
```

For some reason, ^abc in the filepath is treated as special character and sendkeys is not sending it.

Is there a workaround for this or an efficient way of doing this? I'm basically selecting a windows file i.e., through a windows prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd419606.aspx), ^ is a modifier character. Adding it before a character sends that as a control key combo. For example, "^a" would send CTRL+A.

Try wrapping the "^" in braces, like this, to escape it:

```
string filepath="I:\{^}abc\abc\filename.csv";
```

Comment: Awesome. Happy to help.:) 